# Ferramenta para avaliar o gasto de energia dos aplicativos que estão executando no Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, benchmark

eu pesquisei e não fui bem sucedido, então resolvi vir aqui pedir a ajuda de vocês. Gostaria de saber se vocês conhecem alguma ferramenta/aplicativo que consiga avaliar o gasto de energia da bateria dos aplicativos que estão sendo executados no Iphone. Ou seja, que liste os aplicativos que estão sendo rodados e diga quanto de energia cada um está gastando.